# After form submit change div height. django (python)

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I have registration form and one submit button. When I click submit, if there is an error the height of the div increases so I do `height:auto`. But, when I click submit, it changes `div (.continer)` height size. But, after one second page refreshes and get back same css.

```
<button type="submit" name="register" id="btn" onclick="changeSize()">registration</button>
```

```
function changeSize() {
    var el = document.querySelector(".continer").setAttribute("style", "height:auto");
}
```

Comment: sorry, I don't understand all of your question:
Does the height actually change when an error appears? Is this what you want?
what kind of error do you have in your console? do you mean the developer (browser) console or django commandline?

Comment: the class you want to change is `"continer"` is that a typo? do you mean `"container"`?

Comment: if i have empty input and submit i have error messages. after i want change parent container height (auto) default is 400px. when i submit container changed but after 1 second return css and it's 400px. so refresh page.

Comment: what is your javascript code for? If you add content to a div with height:auto it changes the height automatically.. You don't need any javascript for that.. its just how css/html works.

Comment: @sarbot no it's continer

Comment: @sarbot have idea?

Comment: so you want to have a fixed height of the container unless you get an error message? And if you get an error message you want to set the height to auto? 
why do you need to set a fixed height of the container at all?

Comment: @sarbot Yes you understand. What can I do to? not write a fixed height?

Answer (score 2):

Well if you want the height change according to the content inside it, simply put this to your css:

```css
height: content;
```

This will make the height according to the content inside it.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the height is not fixed (because it can change due to error messages for example), I wouldn't set it to a fixed value. If you wan't to keep it fix, you could add a div for the error messages like an error container / placeholder, that has a fixed height too (and maybe hide overflow depending on your priorities). This would make the form larger, but contains space for errors and therefore don't changes it size.

However this sounds like a layout/design question, rather than a question about javascript or django. It's hard to answer such a question by seeing a part of the code and without a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

shoudln't it be container , your spelling is wrong